# C realloc() char ** "invalid next size" error

Tags: c, realloc, sigabrt

```
int parseString(char* input, char*** words, int* size) {
    char *word;

    *words = malloc(sizeof(char));
    word = strtok(input, " \n\t");

    while (word != NULL) {
        (*words)[*size] = malloc(sizeof(word) + 1);
        strcpy((*words)[*size], word);
        (*size)++;
        *words = realloc(*words, ((*size) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        word = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to receive a string (`input`) and split it in words and store the words.

On the forth iteration (always on the forth, never sooner) in the while loop I get a error at `realloc(...)`:

```
realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001641010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After making the suggested changed made by @TaylorBrandstetter and @chux the code looks like this:

```
int parseString(char* input, char*** words, int* size) {
    char *word;

    *words = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    word = strtok(input, " \n\t");

    while (word != NULL) {
        (*words)[*size] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
        strcpy((*words)[*size], word);
        (*size)++;
        *words = realloc(*words, ((*size) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        word = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, allocating a single byte for `*words` is not enough space for an *array* of *pointers* (each being likely 4 or 8 bytes). And `sizeof(word)` will not tell you the size of the string, only the size of a `char*`. Keep in mind, `sizeof` calculations do not occur during runtime.

Comment: You might like to enable your compiler's warnings (command line options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc), then fix your code until no more warnings are issued.

Comment: Suggest `strlen(word)` rather than `sizeof(word)`.

Comment: Thank you: @TaylorBrandstetter the first problem was at `char` instead of `char*` when allocating memory; chux I changed `sizeof(...)` with `strlen(...)` an the size of the words is correctly allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flaw is in the handling of strings:

```
(*words)[*size] = malloc(sizeof(word) + 1);
strcpy((*words)[*size], word);
```

`sizeof(word)` is 4 (well, it may be something else, but it's the size of the pointer).  This needs to be `strlen(word)` instead:

```
(*words)[*size] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
strcpy((*words)[*size], word);
```

And, as @Taylor Brandstetter mentioned, the malloc for `*words` is too small.  In fact, without knowing a maximum number of words in the input, it will be impossible to know the end size of `*words` until the input has been parsed once.

Answer (score 0):

```
    *words = realloc(*words, ((*size) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    word = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
```

The `strtok` function stashes a pointer to where it left off so it can resume when you pass a `NULL` as the first parameter. But your call to `realloc` invalidates the pointer it stored (because it can move the data). So you can't pass `NULL` as the first parameter. But you do.